# Bootstrap 4 collapse to work only if all checkbox is uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show the `upload proof` button if any one/two or all three of checkbox is checked and hide only if all of the checkbox is uncheck.

How can I go about this?

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label class="checkbox"> Age<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proof"></label>
    <label class="checkbox"> Photo<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proof"></label>
    <label class="checkbox"> Address<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proof"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="12">
    <div class="collapse" id="proof">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Upload Proof</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: try toggling using javascript with condition!

Comment: Any sample code that I could look at?

Comment: `<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('[name=FormLabel]').change(function () {
            var count = 0;
            $.each($('[name=FormLabel]'), function () {

                count += (this.checked == true ? 1 : 0);

            });
            if (count >= 2) {
                $('#proof').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#proof').hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: @ElaineByene Can you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code we can check the count of checked checkboxes

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <label class="checkbox"> Age<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_class"></label>
      <label class="checkbox"> Photo<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_class"></label>
      <label class="checkbox"> Address<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_class"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="12">
      <div class="upload_proof hide">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Upload Proof</a>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(event) {
      if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 0)
      {
        if($(".upload_proof").hasClass("hide")){
           $(".upload_proof").removeClass("hide")
         }
      }else{
        if(! $(".upload_proof").hasClass("hide")){
          $(".upload_proof").addClass("hide")
        }
      }
    })
  })
</script>
```

Hope It will help you. Let me know in case of any problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
   $( "input" ).click(function() {
     var checked = $("input:checked").length;
      if (checked == 0) {
        $('#proof').hide();
      } else {
        $('#proof').show();
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label class="checkbox"> Age<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proof"></label>
    <label class="checkbox"> Photo<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proof"></label>
    <label class="checkbox"> Address<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#proof"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="12">
    <div class="collapse" id="proof">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Upload Proof</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should add $('#proof').hide(); on function first line. So that at starting the button will be hidden.

Comment: you can do with many ways. i have choose the easiest way to solve

Comment: its not work as you know because bootstrap function run first for collapse

Comment: It seems to be working but isn't smooth! Thanks though.

Comment: You are right buddy but if you will not remove "collapse" and "data-toggle" things then it will show and hide with effect.

Comment: yes need to remove class="collapse" by default you need to set style="display:none"

Comment: Yeah now you got point, I was talking about after using this it will work smoothly.